# Observing a dynamic HTML table with MutationsObserver

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I can't solve one question with MutationObserver.

Website has a table:

```
<table class='our_table'>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td><span class='size'> S </span></td>

      <td><span class='price'>
        <em> /* first <em> in that <span> */
         450.00
        </em>
       </span>
      </td>

      <td>
       <span class='instock'>
        <em> /* first <em> in that <span> */
         25
        </em>
       </span>
      </td>

   </tr>
    ... here begins next <tr> with 3 tags <td> inside
    ... then more. Can be from 1 to 50 rows, there are 3 <td> in each row.
```

Table looks like..
S    450    25
M    330    60
L    530    30
...

The code is:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations)
{
    // look through all mutations that have just occurred 
    for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) 
    {
        // look through all added nodes of this mutation
        for (var j = 0; j < mutations[i].addedNodes.length; j++)
        {
            var node = mutations[i].addedNodes[j];

            // look through each of 3 <td>'s:
            for (var p = 0; p < node.length; p++)
            {
                console.log('record № ' + p + ', text: ' + node.wholeText )
            };
        }
    }
});

observer.observe(document,
{
    attributes: false,          childList: true, 
    characterData: false,       subtree: true,
    attributeOldValue: false,   attributeFilter: false,
    characterDataOldValue: false
});
```

After the table content is changed, the script result is:

```
<td>№ 0, text: 450.00     // it's a **price**. But should be size, '**S**'
<td>№ 1, text: 450.00     // it's a **price**. All's right.
<td>№ 2, text: 450.00     // it's **price** again. But should be instock, 25 (pcs).

<td>№ 0, text: 550.00     // next <tr> of table is same..
<td>№ 1, text: 550.00
<td>№ 2, text: 550.00
....
```

Should be:

```
<td>№ 0, text: S  // size
<td>№ 1, text: 690.00 // price
<td>№ 2, text: 35 // in stock
...
```

Comment: to me it seems like because you registered to subtree you are receiving all of the mutations, not just the end result.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for reply. Yes. All information inside table updates each time. And i need all data each time (including repeats). I need to 'scan' this table each time and get (print) all data values.

Comment: So it works fine.. you get everything, it's up to you to filter what you don't need

Comment: mm misunderstand a bit. The result of script is a list of 
№ 0, text: 450.00
№ 1, text: 450.00 
№ 2, text: 450.00 

but should be 

№ 0, text: S
№ 1, text: 450.00    
№ 2, text: 25

How i can filter if data contains only price records? I need to view other records - 'size' and 'instock'..

Comment: if you add a codepen I could try and help you out, by the way add characterData: true

Comment: added : http://codepen.io/sameuser/pen/xRoZax

Comment: your codepen doesn't work..

Comment: There is a part of code. Whole code will not work - he required phantomjs. If i have errors in syntax or DOM navigation, can you advice?

Comment: a. You can add any 3rd party library you want in codepen. b. there are no syntax errors in your code. c. add characterData: true in the config, you are looking only on removed/added nodes if your value changes you don't see it. again without a working codepen I can't provide much more help